# Como modificar a transição default de pages no Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Olá, estou dificuldades em encontrar uma solução para  criar transições customizáveis de pages no **Windows Phone 8.1**, pois ao tentar utilizar o toolkit li neste blog (**http://wp.qmatteoq.com**) que ainda não há toolkit para 8.1 ou não é necessário. Gostaria de exemplo, só encontrei para 8.0, ou uma breve explicação do melhor caminho a tomar.

Comment: bom dia! veja se esses exemplos do MSDN pode te ajudar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No Windows Phone 8.1 existem 2 tipos de aplicativos, Windows Phone Store Apps 8.1 e Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

Se você estiver utilizando Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, transições de página é igual o 8.0 com o wptoolkit:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
```

e

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Mas como você esta falando que não tem o toolkit, provavelmente é Windows Phone Store Apps 8.1, então não tem o wptoolkit mesmo e deve usar a classe EntranceThemeTransition do WinRT:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection> 
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Button.Transitions>
</Button>
```

Referência: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx